# findElement(By.linkText is not working in the script. But when I run in the debug mode it's working

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
 <a ng-if="leftNavParent.ChildNavigationLinks.length > 0" href="#!" 
   class="activeContent ng-binding ng-scope" ng- 
   click="leftNavCtrl.leftNavHeaderClicked(leftNavParent)">
   ADMINISTRATIVE MODULE
 </a>
```

I have a web element as shown above tag. And I am finding it as

```
 driver.findElement(By.linkText("ADMINISTRATIVE MODULE")).click();
```

This is comes in left hand side menu bar that is in nested div element as.
My Question is when I run the selenium script it is giving me an exception

```
unknown error: Element <a ng-if="leftNavParent.ChildNavigationLinks.length > 0" href="#!" 
class="activeContent ng-binding ng-scope" ng-click="leftNavCtrl.leftNavHeaderClicked(leftNavParent)">...
</a> is not clickable at point (99, 207). Other element would receive the click: 
<div class="blockUI blockOverlay" style="z-index: 1000; border: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; 
width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0px; left: 0px; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); opacity: 0; 
cursor: wait; position: fixed;"></div>
```

But when I run the script in debug mode it is clicking on that element. 
Any idea why this is happening also sometime it gives

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"ADMINISTRATIVE MODULE"}
```

Comment: Why did you add second exception log? Which one is applicable?

Comment: Try separating it into two steps: define the webelement, optionally place a sleep or wait in between, then click.  It's likely a timing issue since it sometimes finds the element and sometimes does not, but is consistently unable to click.  There are various methods of waiting for both the element to be visible and to be clickable.  Might be invisible blocker element, but likely just timing.

Comment: Thanks @BillHileman ....It worked as per your suggestion. I have a  class where I am finding all element as follows: 

public static WebElement 
    gcp_administrative_Module(WebDriver driver) {
    propelement = driver.findElement(By.linkText("ADMINISTRATIVE 
   MODULE"));
 return propelement;
 }
    }
But I am calling it in LoginClass where I am clicking these element. So is there any simple and efficient way to place wait time  here. ??

Comment: Are you declaring an implicit wait immediately after creating your web driver?

Comment: I'll paste the code below that I use to wait for a page to load.  I generally do this before trying to locate an element or otherwise interact with an element.  I've posted my code as an answer to lots of other questions on here so it's nothing new but rather than point you elsewhere I'll post it again here in case it helps.  Call the routine before getting the web element.

Comment: Yes @BillHileman Please see as follows 

Thread.sleep(3000);
propLoginPageproperty.administrative_Module(driver).click();
Thread.sleep(3000);
propLoginPageproperty.userMgmtClick(driver).click();

Comment: @BillHileman Thanks... ..

Comment: I've addressed your suggested edit (question) but it might not appear until someone else has reviewed and approved my edit/review.  Thanks for selecting it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Today I read [this blog post](https://www.tapir-test.io/blog/simple-page-objects-model/) about simple Page Objects.

Doesn't matter which framework you use, but I like the idea of having [implicit assertions and waits](https://www.tapir-test.io/docs/usingtapir/assertions/).

The main benefit is that you just do not have to care about these synchronization issues by yourself.

If you prefer to use the plain WebDriver API, Bill's suggestion is just fine!

Comment: @BillHileman Can you give me sample code for google.com to wait in between to clicks. I did try but something is going wrong here. Can you please help me

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code instead of sleep or wait statements to be certain the web page has finished loading:

```
public static void waitForPageToLoad() {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {

        public Boolean apply(WebDriver wdriver) {
            return ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");
        }
    });
}
```

**Update**

In answer to your suggested edit, where you posed an additional question, I would place the above method in a helper class, then import that class in your steps class or your page objects.  For example, in my case it's in a class that has a slew of helper objects, most of which wrap various selenium methods like click, sendKeys, etc.  Instead of doing a direct Selenium click in the test code, I leave it up to my page object to do the click for me, and beyond that, I call the waitForPageToLoad within the page object itself, so the test method might say:

```
pageObject.clickLogonButton();
```

In your case, it looks like you're passing the driver object to each of your page object methods, so adjust that as needed.  Then inside the pageobject itself, I might have:

```
public void clickLogonButton() {
    myHelper.waitForPageToLoad();
    logonButton.click();
}
```

Does this clear things up?

Comment: Thanks @BillHileman. I understood the concept of what you are trying to say here . The way I am thinking is much more basic as compare to you and at very preliminary phase :-) . I nee to think and learn such techniques for my automation. Do you suggest any sites which help me to learn such methodologies?
With the share example by me do you suggest any other alternate to do this till I learn the helper class.